# Laravel 5.0 pagination issue

Tags: laravel, pagination

On Laravel I'm using fairly simple query in combination with paginate method:

```
return \DB::table('recipes')
            ->select('recipes.*', \DB::raw('COUNT(votes.id) AS votes'))
            ->leftJoin('votes', 'votes.recipe_id', '=', 'recipes.id')
            ->groupBy('recipes.id')
            ->where('active', 1)->paginate(2);
```

It doesn't matter how many items I want to fetch I'm not getting pagination rendered. What it interesting there is that I'm able to access ?page=2 etc. But pagination is not rendering.

Seems groupBy is making some mess there.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are trying to render it?

Comment: @user3158900 Nothing spectacular there: {!! $recipesArray->render() !!} Standard Laravel pagination render